# Spring boot disable Custom HealthIndicator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've created a custom HealthIndicator which I wants to disable in production until we go live fully.
I'm aware there is a property to disable default health indicators (management.health.defaults.enabled=false), but not for custom HealthIndicators.

Is there any way I can temporarily turn off MyCustomHealthIndicator in application property configuration level?

Comment: how have you created your MyCustomHealthIndicator. Can't you use spring profiles to deactivate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your health indicator bean,

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value='health.indicator.enabled')
@Bean 
class MyHealthIndicator {
}
```

In your application.properties file,

```
health.indicator.enabled=true/false
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 7):

You can use Spring Boot's mechanism without using custom properties. Start by adding an annotation on your class:

```
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("your-health")
```

You can now disable your own health indicator by using the Spring Boot suggested property:

```
management.health.your-health.enabled=false
```

It has the same effect, but it allows you to group your enabled and disabled health indicators together.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("your-health")
```

You can now disable your own health indicator by using the Spring Boot suggested property:

```
management.health.your-health.enabled=false
```

This works when we re-start the app. should it work without re-start?

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55619952/1654265 ?